# VB.Net / Blackberry

Tags: vb.net, blackberry

I have a vb.net application written for PDA's.

Is it possible to write a VB.net application for a Blackberry?

Answer (score 4):

No.  The Blackberry uses Java, either to standard J2ME or to RIM's own APIs.

See their [getting started](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/started/bbdevapproach.jsp) pages.

The very old Mobitex pagers used C++, but again, no VB.net support.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can. There is a product called CrossFire which was produced by a company called AppForge which is now defunct. However, there are several articles on how to use it. Oracle purchased the rights, I believe. I don't think anyone is selling it. The product definitely works. I don't know why the company went defunct.

Nevertheless, I believe the latest version of CrossFire was 6.0. It is sad that you cannot buy it anywhere. However, this would probably solve your needs. Let's just say you can probably find it and it might be 58MB. :)

Comment: Blackberry development is hellish enough without using another potentially-buggy product on top.

Answer (score 1):

En la pagin de blackberry encontre un plugin que se puede instalar en Visual Studio 2005 - 2008 y sirve para trabjar con Blackberry. mira este link http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/rapidappdev/devtools.jsp

Comment: luckily i speak fluent french 
-translation-
On the second page of blackberry found a plugin that can be installed in Visual Studio 2005 - 2008 and serves to trabjar with Blackberry. see this link

Comment: Too bad this is spanish and not french ! :D "On the blackberry site, there is a pluggin that you can install in Visual Studio 2005 - 2008 which makes it working with blackberry. See this link http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/rapidappdev/devtools.jsp"

Answer (score 0):

I've programmed for the BlackBerry using their custom API and Java and (hardly any) J2ME. It was a huge mess, especially when they didn't have a plugin for Eclipse at the time. Recently they did release an Eclipse plugin which should make life much easier.

VB.NET is not officially supported though, sorry.